# Oracle database with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio-2013

I try to create a table "myTest" into oracle database.

```
  create table myTest (id integer primary key, name varchar2(100))
```

It works fine if I use SQL developer or SQL plus, but if I use Visual Stdio 2013 with same login account, I get following error message

```
  The CREATE TABLE SQL construct or statement is not supported.
```

The Select, Update, Delete SQLs are fine in Virtual Studio 2013, but I cannot create table or add column.

What is the problem? Is it Oracle Client don't support that?

Comment: `create` is DDL and `insert/update/delete` is DML. it makes sense that a development IDE like VS wont support DDL. try running the command in sqlplus or sql developer.

Comment: I think you mean "Visual Studio", not "Virtual Studio", right?

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear: VisualStudio won't let you run DDL statements.